# Can I do an offline upgrade to Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-8.1-upgrade

The place I work have recently bought 60 Lenovo Windows 8 Tablets as a trial for a BYOD setup. The only thing they will have access to is our guest wireless and the internet, authenticated through a Smoothwall proxy. It has been requested that they are fully updated and upgraded to Windows 8.1 before deployment. I can configure Windows Updates to run through our proxy server which, although it seems to work, is very slow. WSUS Offline does seem to work a little bit better - it takes a good 30 minutes to build a list of updates.

As they are on a completely separate VLAN they do not (and will not) have access to our WSUS server so I cannot hook them into that to get them updated. I am currently installing 8.1 from the Store but at 2.1GB this is not a quick download and having to do it 60 times will cause me issues. I have looked at installing Windows 8.1 from an ISO but as these are OEM keys I think this will cause other issues - also the fact they do not have a network port means I would have to install from USB which would likely be even slower than downloading from the Store.

Is there a way of downloading 8.1 and installing it locally, or am I doomed to download for all eternity (well, til the 60 are done, anyway?).

Answer (score 0):

If you're providing the devices, it's not BYOD. ;)

Buy one volume licence version of Windows 8.1 and then make an image from that and duplicate it using the VL key provided. It's legal as long as you own an valid OEM license for each device you'll be imaging onto.

Comment: The devices we're testing are "emulated BYOD" - our devices being used in a BYOD setting. This is just a test before rolling it out to a whole school year in a few months, and then the whole school from Sept 2014. Luckily most will be student-owened so we won't have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Only Volume Licence purchasers will have the opportunity for an offline install - all other users must go through Windows Store (regrettably). I'm sure some bright spark will have figure out how to circumvent this but there is currently no official method. So either bring them in-house, so you can take advantage of your VL privileges, or bit the bullet and use the Store.